# How can we show that the BBGKY hierarchy is time symmetric?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am trying to mathematically show that the BBGKY hierarchy for s particles is time symmetric by setting $t\rightarrow -t$. Using the Wikipedia notation for the s-particle we have

$\frac{\partial f_s}{\partial t} + \sum_{i=1}^s \dot{\mathbf{q}}_i \frac{\partial f_s}{\partial \mathbf{q}_i} + \sum_{i=1}^s \left( - \frac{\partial \Phi_i^{ext}}{\partial \mathbf{q}_i} - \sum_{j=1}^s \frac{\partial \Phi_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{q}_i} \right) \frac{\partial f_s}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i} = (N-s) \sum_{i=1}^s \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i} \int \frac{\partial \Phi_{is+1}}{\partial \mathbf{q}_i}\cdot f_{s+1} \,d\mathbf{q}_{s+1} d\mathbf{p}_{s+1}.$

But the problem is I don't know how the negation of time in the density $f_s(q_1...q_s,p_1..p_s,t)$ comes out to fit in with the rest of the equation. This is important since I want to track how we lose time symmetry under the assumption of molecular chaos that sets the  two particles density as the prodcut of two one particle densities.